# Network adapter for HP ScanJet 8300

Tags: networking, usb

I have an HP Scanjet 8300 flatbed scanner, which comes with a USB connection. Now I would like to put it on my network rather than attached to a computer through USB, so I'm trying to find a suitable network adapter. HP sells one for other models (https://store.hp.com/us/en/pdp/hp-scanjet-wireless-adapter-100-accessory), but they don't seem to have one for my device.

So my question is, do you have any suggestions on how to connect my scanner to the network? Is there any kind of general-purpose USB-to-Ethernet (or wifi) adapter? Or a specific one from a third party? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, please buy a scanner with the network option.

The reason ? the scanner probably use TWAIN technology and transfert the data via the USB cable. A network scanner will scan and deliver the scanned document via SMB or via SMTP usually, so it'S different technologie as you can see.

The adapter you find don't fully transform a scanner into a network's one, it only make it possible for a user on a mobile device to scan via the *[HP JetAdvantage Capture](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/hp-jetadvantage-capture/id1208211814)* application.